# Export C# reportviewer control programmatically

Tags: c#, export, reportviewer

Does anyone know if you can programmatically save a report shown in a reportviewer control in C#?

When a report is shown there are "Export to..." buttons and I would like to automate the saving to PDF function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with [ReportViewer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251771(VS.80).aspx)(with [LocalReport.Render Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839(VS.80).aspx)), check "Email a report" example at the http://www.gotreportviewer.com/

Answer (score 3):

```
string _sPathFilePDF = String.Empty;
String v_mimetype;
String v_encoding;
String v_filename_extension;
String[] v_streamids;
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.Warning[] warnings;
string _sSuggestedName = String.Empty;

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportViewer reportViewer1;
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport objRDLC = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport();
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "reportViewer1.rdlc";
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DisplayName  = _sSuggestedName;

objRDLC.DataSources.Clear();
byte[] byteViewer = rptvFlightPlan.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out v_mimetype, out v_encoding, out v_filename_extension, out v_streamids, out warnings);

SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

saveFileDialog1.Filter = "*PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
saveFileDialog1.FileName = _sSuggestedName;
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        FileStream newFile = new FileStream(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
        newFile.Write(byteViewer, 0, byteViewer.Length);
        newFile.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked for me. I'm grateful :) I wasn't even aware that such things could be done, I was trying to request the report page and hacking the resulting HTML/JS code within :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't export to an event as far as `reportviewer` in web forms are concerned.